L1B -> H1B. Consular Stamping in Germany Rejection under Trump
I'm German and came to the US on L1B in 2022 (intra company transfer) i.e. my passport contains L1 visa stamp valid until 2027. Early 2024 my H1B was approved and last month (Oct 2024) my visa status changed from L1B to H1B with I-797A validity until Sep 2027. If I go abroad, I would need a valid H1B stamp on my passport, so I can come inside the US again. Hence, I need to go to Germany to get H1B stamping again.
With Trump in the White House in 2025, in the worst case scenario, could Munich US Consulate reject H1B stamping? Should I rush to Germany and get the H1B stamping in the next 70 days? Please advise.

It's unlikely that the Trump presidency will have any immediate consequences for H1B holder and even less likely for H1B holders from Germany.
This being said, getting H1B stamped in your passport is a tedious and time consuming process that requires careful planning and its probably better to start it sooner than later. You might get stuck abroad for multiple weeks.
Personally I had to do this a few times in various different consulates and found them to be to be highly inconsistent and the staff to be often inconsistent, incompetent, unprofessional, and occasionally outright abusive.
Overview on the process can be found here: https://manifestlaw.com/blog/h1b-visa-stamping-in-usa/ and current wait times for different consulates are here: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html
Note that you can use any consulate in the world, you don't have to use one in Germany.
Also note that the wait and processing times can vary drastically from one consulate to the next even in the same country. Last time we checked in Germany, Frankfurt was a month and Berlin with a hefty expediting fee was about a week. Note that these are just "estimates" and the consulate can take as much time as they feel like.
My wife got stuck in Germany when she went there to visit her dying mother with a small baby in tow. After a lot of research & negotiation we settled on Amsterdam and had 3 different legal entities confirm independently that Amsterdam was indeed offering same day processing for her appointment. When my wife arrived there (exhausted, tired and grieving) the consular agent refused to process her visa because. "He was overworked and underpaid". That's a direct quote. We ended up finagling a business reason for here to get the Visa and apparently that was enough to finally get the agent into gear (but not without significant amounts of pleading and groveling).

Sorry to hear about your situation. If I can use any consulate, I would prefer the one that is geographically and timezone-wise closer to the East coast, so Quebec may be a better option, because I can drive (cheaper) and work from there while H1B is being processed. Is there any scenario why the Stamping may be rejected while applying at a non-home-country consulate?

Absolutely, but most people go through that in Canada without an issue

@m_drinks_coffee: Unfortunately there is ALWAYS  a scenario the stamping can be rejected simply because some officer just happens to be in a bad mood. I had bad experience in Quebec too: made an appointment for H1B stamping for the whole family. I asked whether we all need to appear in person or is it enough if I just bring the paperwork. Person on the phone confirmed that me coming alone is fine. At the appointment the officer refused to stamp by wife and kids passports since they weren't there. At lest he stamped mine so I could get home again (cont.)

(cont.) A week AFTER the appointment we receive a letter from the consulate confirming our appointment (which was already over) and also confirming that my wife and kids would not need to physically be present ??? Apparently I did everything correctly but Mr. Grumpy just wasn't feeling it on the day I was there and somehow the confirmation paperwork(that would have resoled this)  was delayed by 5 weeks.


With Trump in the White House in 2025, in the worst case scenario, could Munich US Consulate reject H1B stamping?

Unless the law changes, there's no reason for them to. While the President themselves are immune from prosecution for illegal acts, consulate employees are not and will continue following the FAM.

Should I rush to Germany and get the H1B stamping in the next 70 days?

No, if the law changes and your H1b status is no longer valid having a piece of paper in your passport is not going to change anything.
